# Can I get the name of the last called CUDA API function?

Tags: c++, reflection, error-handling, cuda, status

I can get the returned status of the last CUDA API call with `cudaGetLastError()`. How about getting its name? I don't see a `cudaGetLastAPICallName()`, but is there some (un)documented equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no you cannot. It is important to keep in mind that

1. `cudaGetLastError()` returns the status of an *earlier* runtime API call, but not necessarily the last one. An asynchronous call can report an error during operation, after it has already returned `cudaSuccess`, in which case its error will be returned by the next API function which returns a status. Parsing the results of his can get particularly complex with concurrent operations in streams.
2. There is at least one operation (kernel launches themselves) which don't have an explicit runtime API call which can be related to any programmer visible source, even though they call a series of documented and private API calls behind the curtains.

It isn't clear to me how either case could be cleanly handled in a way that would give meaningful additional information, especially when some classes of device runtime errors can kill the active context, which looses a lot of state anyway....

Comment: Well, the second case could be handled by either a null string, or some fixed string corresponding to a kernel call, or even the name of the kernel. The first case could be handled so that the API call which caused the error will be the one reported, or at least, you could get both the error code and the API function name together in the same call.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are supposed to wrap all your CUDA calls in a macro that gives you file name and line number. This way, you can easily find the culprit.

Here is an example:

```
template< typename T >
inline void __checkCudaErrors(T result, char const *const func, const char *const file, int const line)
{
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();

    if (cudaSuccess != err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i : checkCudaErrors() CUDA error (#%d): %s.\n",
                file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

#define CCE(val) __checkCudaErrors( (val), #val, __FILE__, __LINE__ )

// ...

CCE(cudaMalloc(...));
CCE(cuda...);
myKernel...;
CCE(nextCudaCall);
```

Comment: I admit, macros are bad in C++, but it's the easiest way to get file name and line number of the caller.

Comment: The filename and line number won't tell me what I need to know. I need the API function name.

Comment: That won't be possible. Besides, not only CUDA API function calls can raise errors. Many CUDA errors are caused by a bad kernel configuration or illegal memory accesses within the kernel.

Comment: @Domi excuse me but the function name is right there, is it not? It's `#val` or `char* func`. You just don't print it.

Comment: @LumpN As talonmies mentioned, that won't give you the name of the culprit.

Comment: @Domi true. Unless you don't use async calls and streams.

Comment: @LumpN even then. The most obvious case is when the error was caused by a kernel call.

Comment: @Domi true again and I'm 100% with talonmies answer. But there is still a lot of value in your macro. Just put `cudaSynchronize` after the kernel call. It will act like a sentinel for kernel errors. Of course it is not the culprit but the kernel is. You'll know which one by file and line number.

Comment: @LumpN bad idea. In many applications, you want to pipeline your kernels, and thus don't want to synchronize after every call.